# What's the purpose of allowedMimeTypes in Flutter Document Picker?

Tags: flutter, mime-types

According to docs, Flutter Document Picker parameter `allowedMimeTypes` allows to list mime types which will be shown in select dialog.

> /// Android only. Allowed MIME types. /// Only files with provided
> MIME types will be shown in document picker. /// If list is null or
> empty - `*/*` MIME type will be used.

Instead, when I use `allowedMimeTypes: ['text/csv']` then `csv` file is not allowed to select in picker. The file is in grey color i.e. it innactive in select screen.

```
  final FlutterDocumentPickerParams params = FlutterDocumentPickerParams(
    allowedMimeTypes: ['text/csv'],
  );
```

So what's the purpose of this parameter then?